# Add user id to blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save

I have a simple blog application. When posts are added, i want the users id to be added to the post so that when a user is logged in, he can only see his posts. The id i want to add to the post, is the id of the user currently logged in.

How and where could the id attribute be added to the posts model?

Session controller:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to blog_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
   def authenticate
     redirect_to log_in_path unless session != nil
   end
end
```

Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    post.user_id = session

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `PostsController`

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  ...
end
```